# How to skip waiting for response from db part when saving data in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

The challenge is that I need to recompute all the data I have in db, after saving a new instance. The computation takes not more than 2 mins, which is fine for my problem. I have custom save method and all I need to do is to go through all items and `item.save()`, but as I said It takes more than 30 sec, so I have issues with 'request timeout'(using Heroku btw). Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

@Uladzislau Malinouski, you can use the asynchronous tools like [`celery`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#tut-celery).

The way it works is that the task that is taking a significant amount of time can be wrapped as an asynchronous task and the computing can be done in the background. You can setup celery on Heroku by following this guide - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku.

If you are using free account and have not provided your card details on Heroku, it'd not be possible for you to add the addon for the broker which are used along with celery-like Redis, Rabbitmq etc. 
In such cases, you may follow this guide to schedule an asynchronous task on Heroku - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python